# Images for layout.tml in web aplication

Tags: html, layout, tapestry

I want to design a layout with images in header. I try to put in layout.tml a division with html component "img" but the atribute "src" depends on the page where you are. How can I solutionate this?

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS is a great option; the other is to let Tapestry generate the proper image URLs for you:

```
<img src="context:images/image.png" alt="Logo"/>
```

In this case `img` is not a component, but is a dynamic element; the `src` attribute is bound to `context:images/image.png1`, which resolves to the proper Tapestry URL to the image; in fact, the URL will be longer than you expect, as it will include (in Tapestry 5.4) a hash code based on the content, and processing will include E-Tag support and a far-future expires header.

Comment: Thanks for answer but, what folder is "context:"?

Comment: You should spend some time reading the Tapestry documentation. `context:` is a binding prefix, which identify how Tapestry should dynamically interpret the rest of the string (`images/image.png`). The `context:` binding prefix indicates that the expression is the path, under the web application context (typically, `src/main/webapp` in your development workspace) for the file; Tapestry will build a URL for this file, but as I indicated, it will have many new capabilities.

Comment: Even if you follow the CSS-based example, _and are using Tapestry 5.4_, you will see that Tapestry has re-written your CSS file with new URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the header blank and use Internal css to make the background of the header change

for example, you create the header block

```
<div class="headerBG"></div>
```

and then in each page 1 include

```
<styles> 
.headerBG {
   background-image: page1Header.png;
}
</styles>
```

in page 2

```
<styles> 
.headerBG {
   background-image: page2Header.png;
}
</styles>
```

and so on

---

The other way would be with javascript

```
<script>
  currPage = location.pathname.substring(1);
  if (currPage == index.html) {
     document.getElementByID("imageid").src="image1.png";
  }
</script>
```